# Convert Java String with GMT date and -6 at end to CST

Tags: java, android, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I have a string with gmt date value and -06:00 at end. What is best way to convert this to CST? I looked at other questions but none of them have -06:00 at end to answer my question.

This is what I tried and it errors out as java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-02-19T11:50:09.5953377-06:00"

```
 private DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSS'Z'");
    private DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    private TimeZone cstTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");

    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(cstTime);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    try {
                System.out.println("cst start date is " + gmtFormat.format("2015-02-19T11:50:09.5953377-06:00"));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Your code example does not compile. The format-method can never throw a ParseException but will complain about string Input.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems before, where I was actually getting dates in 3 different iso formats like that, and was pretty frustrated with it... This isn't pretty, but it may help point you in the right direction...

The 3 formats I was getting the info in:

```
private static final String ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
private static final String ISO_FORMAT2 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
private static final String ISO_FORMAT3 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
```

Actually attempting to parse them (without having to figure out the correct type beforehand, returning a new Date Object in the event all 3 failed so shit doesn't crash because of a damn date formatting exception):

```
public static Date parseIso(String date){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT, Locale.US);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    try {
        return sdf.parse(date);
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.g(TAG, "Failed 1st date parse with " + ISO_FORMAT + " for " + date);

        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT2, Locale.US);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        try {
            return sdf.parse(date);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e2) {
            Log.g(TAG, "Failed 2nd date parse with " + ISO_FORMAT2 + " for " + date);

            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT3, Locale.US);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            try {
                return sdf.parse(date);
            } 
            catch (ParseException e3) {
                Log.g(TAG, "Failed 3rd date parse with " + ISO_FORMAT3 + " for " + date);                   
            }
        }
    }
    return new Date();
}
```

And then for actually converting that date to a localized date:

```
public static String format(long mils, String format){
    return format(getInstance(mils), format);
}

public static String format(Calendar calendar, String format){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    return sdf.format(new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(new Date().getTime())));
}

public static Calendar getInstance(long timeInMils){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMils);
    return cal;
}
```

So now you can basically call

```
CalendarHelper.format(myDateObject.getTime(), "MMM dd, yyyy");
```

and it will return the localized, formatted date from the original UTC date you received.

Again, not pretty, but I hope this can point you in the right direction for converting between the UTC and client's time zone. Best of luck~

PS. I think ISO_FORMAT_3 is the one that will actually help you. I guess I probably could have started with that information, but I'm not a bright man.

Answer (score 0):

## ISO 8601

You seem to misunderstand the meaning of the input string, `2015-02-19T11:50:09.5953377-06:00`. You do not have a "gmt date value".

That format appears to be the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

- The `T` in the middle separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion.
- The `-06:00` at the end is an offset from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). It means "the date-time value shown here is six hours behind UTC".

## CST

So, if by `CST` you mean [Central Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone) (some of the middle parts of the Americas continents), then you need have no conversion to perform. That string with the time 11:50 means "almost noon in Illinois, Arkansas, and Louisiana". If you *add* 6 hours to 11:50, you would learn the UTC (GMT) date-time at that same moment: 17:50 on same date.

## Avoid 3-4 Letter Codes

By the way, avoid using three or four letter time zone codes such as "CST". Those codes are not standardized nor unique. [Many duplicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) exist. For example, take `CST`:

- Central Standard Time (Americas)
- China Standard Time
- Central Standard Time (Australia)
- Central Summer Time (Australia)
- Cuba Standard Time

Instead use [proper time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Most of these are continent plus a slash plus a city/region. Examples: `America/Regina`, `America/Monterrey`, and `America/Indiana/Knox`.

## Joda-Time | java.time

The java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

Use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package built into [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29). The java.time package is inspired by Joda-Time but is re-architected. Each has its own strengths and weaknesses.

Both Joda-Time and java.time use ISO 8601 formats as their defaults for both parsing and generating string representations of date-time values.

As this Question is really a duplicate with hundreds of such Questions and Answers already posted, I'll give just one quick example.

```
String input = "2015-02-19T11:50:09.5953377-06:00";
DateTimeZone zoneAmerica_Regina = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Regina" );
DateTime dateTimeAmericaRegina = new DateTime( input, zoneAmerica_Regina ); 
DateTime dateTimeLosAngeles = dateTimeAmericaRegina.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" ) );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeAmericaRegina.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

## Fractional Seconds

Your input string has a very small fraction of a second. Joda-Time (like java.util.Date) handles only [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution — three digits after the decimal point. The java.item package handles [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. Some systems use [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) resolution, such as database like [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org). And some systems follow the old [Unix convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of whole seconds.